# what does the gwt PlaceTokenizer actually do?

Tags: java, gwt

I really doesnt understand what the PlaceTokenizer is doing?
does he convert the class name of a place into a string so that the gwt history mechanism can use it to put it into the browsers url?
thats what i understand but iam not sure if this is right.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces#Places and T Broyers explanation here - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/tSaVtGvrVH0

Answer (score 5):

First, `PlaceTokenizer` is only used in combination with the generator for `PlaceHistoryMapper` (i.e. if you `GWT.create()` an interface that extends `PlaceHistoryMapper`; you're free to instead implement that interface in a concrete class if you prefer). The generator forces the *history tokens* (the part after the `#` in the URL) to be composed of a prefix and a *place token*. The prefix is used to match with a given `PlaceTokenizer` type, and is either given by the `@Prefix` annotation on the tokenizer or it defaults to the simple name of the place handled by the tokenizer.

When parsing a *history token* (when `handleCurrentHistory()` is called at initialization time, or when you navigate using your browser's history), after the prefix has been matched to a `PlaceTokenizer` and an instance of that tokenizer has been retrieved (from the factory if using a `PlaceHistoryMapperWithFactory`, or created using its default zero-arg constructor), the *place token* is passed to the `getPlace` method and the tokenizer is expected to instantiate a place corresponding with the *place token*.

When serializing a place (when you navigate through `PlaceController#goTo(Place)` in the app), a tokenizer is retrieved based on the type of the place (matched against the generic parameter of the tokenizer) and the place is given to `getToken`, which is expected to return a *place token* for the place. The `PlaceHistoryHandler` will then prepend the prefix and update the URL.

The *place token* can be anything, but is based on the data contained by the place (its fields), not its type (this is reflected as the prefix of the *history token*)